# What is the purpose of navigator.connection.saveData?

Tags: javascript, html

I see the w3c site in **navigator.connection.saveData** object but I didn't understand what is the use? and where can I use it on my website?

Please anyone can explain me about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Network Information API spec](http://wicg.github.io/netinfo/#-dfn-savedata-dfn-attribute), it looks like `saveData` attribute indicates whether the user has requested that data usage be reduced by the user agent:

> The `saveData` attribute, when getting, returns true if the user has requested a reduced data usage mode from the user agent, and false otherwise.
>
> **NOTE**
>
> The user may enable such preference, if made available by the user agent, due to high data transfer costs, slow connection speeds, or other reasons.

---

Regarding your second question,

> Where can I use it on my website?

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection#Browser_compatibility) (and [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=network)), `navigator.connection` API is currently only supported in Chrome versions 61+. It will not work with other browsers yet.

In fact, according to CanIUse.com, Chrome only supports the `downlink`, `effectiveType` & `rtt` attributes on `navigator.connection`. So you might not be able to use `saveData` on Chrome either.

Answer (score 2):

so. navigator.connection.saveData saving data about user connection.
Definition of Navigator Connection

> The Network Information API provides information about the system's
>   connection in terms of general connection type (e.g., 'wifi',
>   'cellular', etc.). This can be used to select high definition content
>   or low definition content based on the user's connection. The entire
>   API consists of the addition of the NetworkInformation interface and a
>   single property to the Navigator interface: Navigator.connection.

Example code:

```
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
var type = connection.type;

function updateConnectionStatus() {
  console.log("Connection type changed from " + type + " to " + connection.type);
}

connection.addEventListener('change', updateConnectionStatus);
```